# Using Node locally like a console in the browser, lots of errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am learning Javascript and I wish to "interact" with my program to see if I wrote functions properly. When I say interact I mean create objects, call recursive functions, get/set properties, etc.

When I load my script in Chrome I can do all of this in the console (works properly). However, when I try the same approach on my Mac using Node I get all sorts of weird behaviour.

**Code example:**

```
"use strict";

// simple recursive function
let countDownFrom = (num) => {
    if (num === 0) return;

    console.log(num)
    countDownFrom(num - 1)
}


// Closures
var createPet = function(name) {
    var sex;

    return {
        setName: function(newName) {
        name = newName;
    },
    getName: function() {
        return name;
    },
    getSex: function() {
        return sex;
    },
    setSex: function(newSex) {
        if(typeof newSex === "string" && (newSex.toLowerCase() === "male" || newSex.toLowerCase() === "female")) {
            sex = newSex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 1.** 
While in a directory that holds my test.js file I tried the `node test.js` command doesn't print anything to terminal, it just moves to a new line.

> js git:master ❯ node test.js
>   js git:master ❯

This is of course logical - the script gets loaded into the memory, it get's executed, the result is printed onto a screen (nothing visible since no function calls have been made within the script) and after that the memory is freed (variables destroyed). It is obvious that from here I cannot do something like `countdownFrom(10);` or `var pet = createPet("Charlie");`.

**Example 2.**
When I enter interactive mode (REPL) I do a:

> require('./test')

which prints an empty object `{}` onto a new line. If I then try my `countDownFrom(10);` I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: countDownFrom is not defined
>       at repl:1:9
>       at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:269:27)
>       at bound (domain.js:287:14)
>       at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
>       at REPLServer. (repl.js:439:12)
>       at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
>       at REPLServer.emit (events.js:182:7)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)

It seems to me that Node does not load and "hold" the script like a browser does. I wish to be able to do things like these:

```
var pet = createPet(/name/);
pet.getName();
pet.setSex("female"); 
// ... etc
```

P.S. I did try loading the whole test.js in a variable like so `var t = require("./test");` but also no luck:

> '> t.createPet("Charlie");
>   TypeError: t.createPet is not a function

What is the right way to go about this? Thanks!